# Determine KE of electron given momentum & mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum

Some info:

- wavelength of electron: $2.78 \times 10^{-10}$
- momentum of electron: $2.38 \times 10^{-24}$

Determine KE of electron. In a provided hint: $KE = \frac{p^2}{2m}$. So I have:

$$KE = \frac{2.38 \times 10^{-24}}{2 \times 9.11 \times 10^{-31}} = 1.31 \times 10^6$$. But provided answer is $3.10 \times 10^{-18}$. How do I get this?

Comment: You didn't square the numerator.

Comment: Wow ... that was stupid of me ...

Comment: lol it happens to the best of us. Well, to me at least :P

Comment: One word for this: **UNITS**!! Every time I see students do this on assignments I'm marking I risk having a stroke. Without knowing the context (i.e., guessing your wavelength is in meters) I have no way of knowing the relevant physics... i.e. does relativity matter or not, etc.? If meters no, if angstroms yes. :) I'll stop ranting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p=2.38 \times 10^{-24}\left[\frac{\text {kg m}}{\text s}\right]$

$m_e=9.11\times10^{-31} [\text {kg}]$

$$\begin{align*}
KE = \frac{p^2}{2m}
&=\frac{\left(2.38\times10^{-24}\left[\frac{\text{kg m}}{\text s}\right]\right)^2}{2\times9.11\times10^{-31}[\text{kg}]}\\&=\frac{2.38^2\times10^{-24\times2}\left[\frac{\text{kg m}}{\text s}\right]^2}{2\times9.11\times10^{-31}[\text{kg}]}\\
&=\frac{5.6644\times10^{-48}}{18.22\times10^{-31}}\left[\frac{\text{kg m}^2}{\text s^2}\right]\\
&=\frac{5.6644}{18.22}\times10^{-48+31}[\text J]\\
&=0.310889\times10^{-17}[\text J]\\&=3.11\times10^{-18}[\text J]
\end{align*}$$.

Comment: While I truly encourage this answer, I'm quite suspicious whether it helps solving it..? :O

Comment: -1 While this answer is extremely helpful to the poster it is in no way helpful to anyone else or the site.